# Delete confirmation displayed twice

Tags: yii2, confirmation

I have a extremely basic implementation of `ActionColumn` in my Yii2 application:

```
[
    'class' => \yii\grid\ActionColumn::className(),
    'template' => '{delete}'
],
```

Whenever I click on `delete` button, I see `Are you sure you want to delete this item` standard JS confirmation displayed **twice**. What am I missing?

Is this a bug in Yii2 (since I'm using basic / core / default implementation of this button)?

Comment: show please ActionColumn class

Comment: Try to update composer.

Comment: @Alex This is framework class, not custom one.

Comment: @Alex I did. It is in the question. There is nothing more in my `ActionColumn`.

Comment: @arogachev `composer self-update` says, that I have the newest version. `composer update` says: `Nothing to install or update`.

Comment: I mean actually to update to the latest `dev-master` version (not sure if it's suitable for you or not).

Comment: @arogachev Let's just say, that I pick the easiest solution. If customer ever notice this problem, I offer him either waiting for 2.0.4 or updating to `dev-master`! :>

Answer (score 1):

As per [*pana1990*'s post on Yii Framework forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63097-delete-confirmation-displayed-twice/page__view__findpost__p__278445), this is a framework bug, that [is fixed](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/3abc07d16cb4f877cdff9e24d97269345a6c8b44) in Yii 2.0.4.

Waiting for 2.0.4 to become official release (currently *under development*) to grab this fix.